# .fadeIn works for button press, but not for keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two divs and I'm trying to have only one div visible at a time.  When I press the 1 key, I want div1 to fadeIn (if it hasn't already), and for div2 to fadeOut (if it hasn't already).  Then if I press the 2 key, the opposite should happen; with div2 fading in and div1 fading out.  My code is below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#div2").fadeOut();
});
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode==49)
    $("#div2").fadeOut();
    $("#div1").fadeIn();
    });
    if (e.keyCode==50)
    $("#div1").fadeOut();
    $("#div2").fadeIn();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Fade in div1 by pressing the 1 key.  Fade out div1 and fade in div 2 by pressing the 2 key.</h1>
<div id="div1">1</div>
<div id="div2">2</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This was working when I was using buttons, but not now for keypresses.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The syntax is incorrect in your `if` statements. They should be `if(e.keyCode==49) {  /* do stuff between the braces */ }`

Comment: ... and the `keydown` function ends after that.

Answer (score 0):

Just syntax *keep eyes on console for errors* for sure with your code you'll get `syntax error`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#div2").fadeOut();
    $(document).keydown(function(e){
      if (e.keyCode==49){
        $("#div2").fadeOut();
        $("#div1").fadeIn();
      }
      if (e.keyCode==50){
        $("#div1").fadeOut();
        $("#div2").fadeIn();
      }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Fade in div1 by pressing the 1 key.  Fade out div1 and fade in div 2 by pressing the 2 key.</h1>
<div id="div1">1</div>
<div id="div2">2</div>
```